# MySQL: Insert into multiple tables in same query with BEGIN&COMMIT

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert into multiple tables in same query by using BEGIN and COMMIT.
It seems the error occur at begin.

here is my SQL command

```
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Product (pName, pBrand, pCategory, pSize, pQuantity, pPrice, pDetail)
        VALUES('$name', '$brand', '$category', '$size', '$quantity', '$price', '$detail')
    INSERT INTO Image (iName, iExt, iSize, pID)
        VALUES('$img_name', '$img_ext', '$img_size', LAST_INSERT_ID());
    COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot to add semicolon `;` (*or the terminator*) after the keyword `BEGIN`

[**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/251bd/1)