# MySQL: Trouble with LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multiple tables in same query with table2 retrieve the id from table1

Here's my sql code

```
 $q = "
    INSERT INTO Product (pName, pBrand, pCategory, pSize, pQuantity, pPrice, pDetail)
        VALUES('$name', '$brand', '$category', '$size', '$quantity', '$price', '$detail');
    INSERT INTO Image (iName, iExt, iSize, pID)
        VALUES('$img_name', '$img_ext', '$img_size', LAST_INSERT_ID());";

 $mysqli->query($q);
```

It shown the syntax error.
but I copied the output of $q to Run in SQL query at phpMyAdmin it worked.
Could you anyone point me out where is my mistake?

```
    INSERT INTO Product (pName, pBrand, pCategory, pSize, pQuantity, pPrice, pDetail)
        VALUES(....); #1 row affected
    INSERT INTO Image (iName, iExt, iSize, pID)
        VALUES(....); #1 row affected
```

Comment: I don't believe that you can run multiple statements with a single query call

Comment: Don't know if it is related or duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12649706/1369235)

Comment: You may need to look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples)

Comment: @TimG he's already using mysqli, a better advice is to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that you can run multiple statements with a single query call; you need to call `mysqli_multi_query` instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "
    INSERT INTO Product (pName, pBrand, pCategory, pSize, pQuantity, pPrice, pDetail)
        VALUES('$name', '$brand', '$category', '$size', '$quantity', '$price', '$detail');
    INSERT INTO Image (iName, iExt, iSize, pID)
        VALUES('$img_name', '$img_ext', '$img_size', LAST_INSERT_ID());";
$arr=explode(";",$q)
for($i=0;isset($arr[$i]);$i++)//or use limit($arr) in place of isset
{

 $mysqli->query('"'.$arr[$i].'"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    By default, mysql_query() and mysql_real_query() 
interpret their statement string argument 
as a single statement to be executed, and you process
 the result according to whether 
the statement produces a result set 
(a set of rows, as for SELECT) 
or an affected-rows count (as for INSERT, UPDATE, and so forth).
```

read C API Support for mysql