# MySQL error 1064 - doing two insert statements in one query; what is wrong with this?

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with my query? I'm trying to insert execute both the insert statements with the one query, but I get this error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INSERT INTO todo (title, slug, description, user_id) VALUES
>   (?, ?, ?, ?); ' at line 2

I have read the error but I don't see anything wrong with that insert statement, what am I missing here?

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO todo (title, slug, description, user_id)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);

    SET @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO todo_category (todo_id, category_id)
    VALUES (@last_insert_id, ?),
           (@last_insert_id, ?),
           (@last_insert_id, ?);
COMMIT;
```

The question marks will be consumed into values before the query is executed.

Comment: You appear to be using [`MS SQL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) syntax where you should be using [`MySQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) syntax.

Comment: The syntax is correct. Make sure you're really replacing the question marks before execution.

Comment: How are you attempting to execute this? If it is php (or another API that does not allow multiple queries), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679241/php-mysql-begin-commit-not-working) is probably your issue.

Comment: I am using Go with an sql driver that works similar to `fmt.Sprintf` in Go, which consume the question marks with values separated by commas after the query string itself. Similar to how one might do this in PHP or another language.

Answer (score 1):

You must be asking yourself: "what are my values"?

It seems you're missing the prepare statement. [Check this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to catch it up.